# Async web task to return XML formatted string

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task, webclient

I wish to create an async task which will request data from an online API.
All the resources I've found through google had not helped me solve this thus I am asking now.

So far the program is very simple, consisting of:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Collections.Specialized;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, world! Hit ANY key to continue...");
        Console.ReadLine();
        //Task<string> testgrrr = RunAsync();
        //string XMLString = await testgrrr;
        var XMLString = await RunAsync(); //The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'.
        //Some XML parsing stuff here
    }
}

public async Task<string> RunAsync()
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var item = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
        item.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("typeid", "34"));
        item.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("usesystem", "30000142"));
        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(item);
        // HTTP POST
        response = await client.PostAsync("", content);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Console.WriteLine("Data:" + data);
            return data; //XML formatted string
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

I want to be able to have multiple of these web requests running in parallel and have them return the XML String to be parsed. The code does not work with the following errors:

```
An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'EVE_API_TestApp.Program.RunAsync()'  
The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'.
```

I am new to C# and async/await. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Changing it from public to static does indeed remove the first error. Are you saying *main* has to be marked async as well?

Comment: Thanks! That fixed everything *so far...*!
Cheers!

Comment: Cool. I've added my comments into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Main` cannot be marked `async`, so what you need to do is call `Task.Wait` from your `Main`. This is one of the *rare exceptions* to the general rule that you should use `await` instead of `Wait`.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  MainAsync().Wait();
}

static async Task MainAsync()
{
  Console.WriteLine("Hello, world! Hit ANY key to continue...");
  Console.ReadLine();
  var XMLString = await RunAsync();
  //Some XML parsing stuff here
}
```

Comment: Could you quickly explain why `Main()` should not be async? In your example, should i treat `MainAsync()` as my `main()` and run everything in/from there?
Cheers!

Comment: The compiler will not allow an `async Main`. The reason is because `async` methods can return (i.e., at an `await`) before they're done executing. If `Main` returns, your app exits. Yes, you should do everything in `MainAsync`.

Comment: Ahh cheers. I hadn't actually tried compiling the `async Main` as it was late and I headed straight to bed!